# Acess component variable inside onClick function of Chart Js

Tags: angular, charts, ionic3

I have the following component, but I can't print `test` variable value inside onClick function of Chart.

```
export class EntradaSaidaComponent {

  @ViewChild('graficoDeBarraTemplate')
  private graficoDeBarraTemplate;
  graficoDeBarra: Chart;
  test:any = "Test";

  ngOnInit(){
    this.graficoDeBarra = new Chart(this.graficoDeBarraTemplate.nativeElement, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Entrada", "Saída"],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: ["#00b050", "#00b0f0"],
          data: [this.dashboard.totalReceber, this.dashboard.totalPagar],
          label: this.sharedProvider.formatMoeda(this.dashboard.totalReceber)
        },
        {
          backgroundColor: ["#03A9F4"],
          data: [],
          label: this.sharedProvider.formatMoeda(this.dashboard.totalPagar)
        },
      ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
      },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      onClick: function(){
        console.log(this.test);
      },
    },
  });
  }

}
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the arrow function

```
onClick: () => {
    console.log(this.test);
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Context issue.

Either (yes, this is a strange syntax for an object, but trust me it works)

```
onClick(){
    console.log(this.test);
  },
```

Or

```
onClick: () => console.log(this.test),
```

Comment: Thank you man, but I need to accept only one and David answered some seconds before

Comment: @renanzin No problem, I'm here to help, not for the reputation (and as you can see I have plenty) !

Comment: man how to acess event and array of click chart js inside this function? for example `chartClickEvent(event, array) ` it works but I can't acess the component variable

Comment: @renanzin sorry, you'll have to be more specific, I don't get what you want there

Comment: I will ask a new question