# Access data about chart js instance and component variable

Tags: angular, charts, ionic3

I have the following onClick function inside my ChartJS instance. It works perfectly to [access component variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56806373/5360385)

```
onClick: () => {
    console.log(this.test);
  },
```

Now I need to get some informations about the chart.

**For example:**

Using this function bellow I can access event of click and array but I can't access component variable like in the first arrow function

```
chartClickEvent(event, array) {
    const ENTRADA = 0, SAIDA = 1;
    if (array[0]) {
      let columnIndex = array[0]._index;
      if (columnIndex == ENTRADA) {
        console.log(this.test);
      }
    }
  }
```

It's shows `undefined` when I try to print component variable

```
onClick: chartClickEvent,
```

How to access both? Data about chart and component variable

Comment: `onClick: (event, array) => this.chartClickEvent(event, array)`

Comment: @David it's works like a charm. Could you create a answer for that?

Comment: It's alright, no worries =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function:

```js
onClick: chartClickEvent.bind(this)
```

What happens here is when `chartClickEvent` is being executed **the scope is different** and so the `this` is not what you expected.

The `bind` function returns a new function that is bound to the `this` you defined.

You can, of course, use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) there as well:

```js
onClick: (event, array) => chartClickEvent(event, array)
```

Comment: Thank you man. David answered first in the comments area but If he does not create a answer I going to accept yours